# Is it normal for the tilt want on blinds to be slanted?

Tags: blinds

I recently purchased new blinds for my house, and the install team installed them like this:

[image]

I asked them why the tilt wants are crooked and not parallel to the wall, and they said this is normal and not a problem. They said that the company values "function over form." For almost $3,000, I think that is not correct.

I tried googling and did not see any pictures on the internet of installs done this way. Is this normal? Are there any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not normal and not ok.  Wand should not rub blind.  If you raise the blind rapidly, the wand will go flying out!  Also does the blind snag on the wand as you raise it?

Comment: It doesn't really snag on the wand, but it certainly rubs against it.

Comment: Looks to me like the wands are just being pushed inward by the way the slats are stacked.  Sometimes if the slats aren't completely flat when you pull the blinds up, the stack will shift a little bit.  Should be able to push on the stack and shift it toward the window.

Comment: This can be as simple as exactly how the slats stack themselves as they are raised, which can be affected by the angle they're set to when you lift. At worst I'd call it "annoying but harmless." Others may disagree.

Comment: I had that in a dorm room. I added two super magnets, one in the end of the wand, and one up in the top channel, so that it met the wand magnet when folded up. This held them out of the way and out of sight.

Comment: @dandavis thank you so much. I was finally able to get that installed, and it worked amazing!